# how to make url in rails app that is not domain specific

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making a dynamic URL in my rails app like

`http://localhost:3000?#{something}=#{something1}`

How do I get rid of the hardcoded domain name (localhost in this case).  I want to deploy this app to heroku and heroku will give its own domain name.  I don't want to again change my code to suit the domain name that heroku gives.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `localhost:3000` with `request.host_with_port`

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Request.html#M000521